# KOMA-script modify part* page

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, book-design, parts

My document has parts and *parts. I redefined the `\part` to print only a decorated number, that's working fine. Now I need `\part*` to print a decoration using the same style as `\part`. `\part*{}` ships out an empty page, which makes sense because it must not have a line for a part number. I can more or less do it by hand, using `\clearpage` and putting just the decoration on the page. But then both the horizontal and the vertical alignment of the decorations come out different to the part page layout. How can I make `\part*` print my decoration on the part page?

Note: I don't have a table of contents, so that's not a concern.

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\adforn{21}~\thepart~\adforn{49}}
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\begin{document}
\part{}
\lipsum

\clearpage
\begin{centering}
\vspace*{\fill}
\Huge\adforn{21}\adforn{11}\adforn{49}
\vfill
\end{centering}
\clearpage

\lipsum

\part*{}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can local redefine `\partformat` to print`\adforn{11}` instead of the part number. Then use `\part{}` and correct the part counter by adding -1.

```
\documentclass[open=any]{scrbook}
\usepackage{adforn}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\arabic{part}}
\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\adforn{21}~\thepart~\adforn{49}}
\renewcommand*{\partpagestyle}{empty}

\newcommand*{\decoratedpage}{%
  {\renewcommand*{\partformat}{\adforn{21}~\adforn{11}~\adforn{49}}
  \part{}
  \addtocounter{part}{-1}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{}
\blinddocument

\decoratedpage
\blinddocument

\part{}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

There is no problem with a possible table of contents: because of the empty argument  `\part{}` will not get an automatic entry.